# How to work with high order functions inside lists in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell by myself and I have a lot of doubts about how

```
[f x | ......]
```

works. For example I have this expression:

```
[ f x | f<- [(+1),(*2),(3-)], x<-[1..(f 1)]]
```

And it returns:

```
[2,3,2,4,2,1]
```

But I don't really understand how it comes to that conclusion.

Can somebody help me with a little bit of explanation? I've read the documentation several times but I don't get it.

Thanks!

Comment: Note this only works when all your functions have the same signature, which they do as `(+1)`, `(*2)`, `(3-)` are all `Num a => a -> a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f <- [(+1), (*2), (3-)]
```

says "pick any value of `f`" from the list.

```
x <- [1..(f 1)]
```

says "pick any `x` from the list `[1..f 1]`, for the `f` we've chosen". If `f` was chosen to be eg. `(3-)` in step 1, then this list will be `[1,2]`.

```
[ f x | ... ]
```

says "produce the value `f x` in the output list, for the `f` and `x` we've chosen previously", eg. if `f = (3-)` and `x = 2`, then we include `f x = 3 - 2 = 1` in the list. This happens to be the final value in the list you got as output.

This is done for all `f` and `x` combinations, until we get the final output.

---

The below diagram illustrates how the combinations of `f` and `x` produce the output.

```
[ 2  ,  3  ,  2  ,  4  ,  2  ,  1 ]
 x=1   x=2   x=1   x=2   x=1   x=2
   f=(+1)      f=(*2)      f=(3-)
```

Read it as choices being made from the bottom up: we pick `f`, then we pick `x`, then we include `f x` in the output.